# How to use the parameter passed through url in validation of form

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have following model:

```
class ArticleUser(models.Model):
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
   fullname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
   create_time =models.DateTimeField()
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       ''' On save, update timestamps '''
       self.create_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
       super(ArticleUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

   class Meta:
       unique_together = (('email','article'),)
```

I am passing the article_id through the url:

```
url(r'^articlebuffer/(?P<mid>\d+)/$',views.articlebuffer, name="articlebuffer"),
```

I need to use the article_id in the validation of the form so that article and email are unique together. How can I achieve it in the formset as well as in form

Here is my view using formset:

```
def articlebuffer(request,mid):
   ArticleBufferFormSet = modelformset_factory(ArticleUser,exclude=('article','create_time'))    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ArticleBufferFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)                
            for instance in instances:
                instance.article_id = mid
                try:
                    instance.save()
                except:
                    error="Unique Constraint Error"                    

            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        formset = ArticleBufferFormSet(queryset= ArticleUser.objects.none())
    return render (request, 'tracking/createarticlebuffer.html',{'formset':formset,
                                                       })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include it with your POST data when you create a new `ArticleBufferFormSet`

```
formset = ArticleBufferFormSet(dict(request.POST.items() + {'article_id': article_id}))
```